# convert "1.hour" to 1.hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to convert "1.hour" string to 1.hour and "2.hours" to 2.hours in ruby? Actually I am getting this value from a dropdown in a form. I want to add it to `Time.now` by something like this

```
time = Time.now + get_method(params[:hours_or_days])
```

where `params[:days_or_hours]` may be "2.hours" or "1.hour" or "1.day". I want to get the method conversion of these strings. Is it possible? (by some method like `send`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't do this with `eval` because then someone using your website could send any string of Ruby code for you to execute, which would be a bad security hole for your site. You could validate the string using a Regexp or a whitelist but that would be messy.

I think you should be evaluating the `1.hour` and `2.hours` and so on when rendering your form. Something like this:

```
<%= select_tag(:days_or_hours, options_for_select({ "1 hour" => 1.hour, "2 hours" => 2.hours })) %>
```

This generates HTML like this:

```
<select name="days_or_hours">
  <option value="3600">1 hour</option>
  <option value="7200">2 hours</option>
</select>
```

Now the number of seconds will be passed when the form is submitted, and you don't have to worry about whether the user chose hours or days. Your code simply becomes:

```
time = Time.now + params[:days_or_hours].to_i
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it would be to split the string:

```
>> duration, method = '1.hour'.split('.')
 => ["1", "hour"]
>> duration.to_i.send(method)
 => 3600 seconds
```

Of course, you'd definitely want to protect this in some way:

```
if duration_string =~ /^\d+\.(hour|minute|second)s?$/
   # ...
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the `eval` keyword.

e.g. `Time.now + eval("1.hour")`

Edit:
As has been pointed out many times, while you *can* do this, you shouldn't.

Comment: @everyone..Please dont down vote their answer...They answered my question convert "1.hour" to 1.hour correctly..they just didnt think of the side effects in my case..if the title of the question alone is taken their answer is perfectly correct..it is just that someone had a better answer.

Comment: Down votes can occur for answers that have dangerous side effects. If the answerer understands there are dangerous side effects it should have been noted clearly in the answer which would have mitigated the danger concerns and avoided the down votes.

Comment: @theTinMan, yes, I do agree now.